# the best way to transfer or copy a web application from IIS in one server to another IIS in another server

Tags: iis-7

I have a webApp in my IIS 7.5 on windows server 2008 now I need to move this particular web app (not all of them) to another IIS 7.5 on the new windows server 2008 R2.

Can anyone please suggest?

thanks

Answer (score 2):

Web Deploy is probably the best, it can do it server to server (ie live sync/migration) as well as allow you to generate a package that can then be installed in the other server:

http://www.iis.net/download/WebDeploy

It includes GUI (extends IIS Manager) as well as command line options, can do it over HTTPS or directly using the IIS configuration APIs. It supports moving configuration, content, GAC, DLLs, Database, Certificates, SSL settings and more.